# Executing exe file from nodejs

Tags: node.js, exe, child-process

I'm setting up a new application for my final project. I'm trying to execute an exe file using node.js, but it looks that it's not working right.
I don't get any errors...

```
var {execFile} = require('child_process');
var executablePath = "C:\\Users\\MyUser\\Desktop\\finalProject\\routes\\api\\testcpp.exe";

const child = execFile(executablePath, ['--version'], (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
        throw error;
    }
    console.log(stdout);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var {execFile} = require('child_process');
var executablePath = "C:/Users/MyUser/Desktop/finalProject/routes/api/testcpp.exe";
const child = execFile(executablePath, ['--version'], (error, stdout, stderr) => {
if (error) {
  throw error;
}

console.log(stdout);
});
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, still not working..everything seems ok, no errors.

Comment: I have edited the answer.Just copy the code and see if it works.I have checked it in my system.It is working fine.The path you are trying to send is in incorrect format

Comment: still nothing..its not even executing console.log('TEST') inside the execFile before the "if(error)" part..

Comment: for me its working,i suggest you to see if there is any other problem in your system or in nodejs..